# Como pegar duas tabelas sem uni-las com o query builder do Zend1.12?

Tags: php, sql, query, zend

Baseado na [documentação do Zend 1.12](https://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.select.html), usando o query builder:

Como eu seleciono duas tabelas apenas com vírgula sem `joinInner`:

Exemplo:

```
SELECT TABELA1 FROM 
(
 BLABLABLA...
) A, 
(SELECT TABELA2) B
```

Pra entender meu problema, esse é o código:

```
 $selectRankQuery = $this->dbTable->select()
        ->setIntegrityCheck(false)
       ->from(array('opn' => 'olympic_players_niveis'),
       array(
           'opn.user_id',
           'SUM(opn.points) as total_points'
       ));

       if ($olympic_id != null) {
          $selectRankQuery->where('opn.olympic_id = ? ', $olympic_id);
       } else {
          $selectRankQuery->joinInner(array('ol' => 'olympics'),
            'opn.olympic_id = ol.ID and ol.active = 1',
            array(
            ));
       }

       $selectRankQuery->group('opn.user_id');

       $init = new Zend_Db_Expr("SELECT @rank := 0");


        $select = $this->dbTable->select()
            ->setIntegrityCheck(false)
            ->from(array('rank_res' => $selectRankQuery),
            array(
                'rank_res.*',
                new Zend_Db_Expr('@rank := @rank + 1 rank')
            ))
            //o que eu uso aqui para ficar uma vírgula ????
            ->join(array('init' => $init));

             $r = $select->assemble();
```

Só preciso iniciar a variável `@rank := 0` no select;

Eu tentei isso, mas a query não mostrou o valor de ranking:

 `->from(array('rank_res' => $selectRankQuery, 'init' => $init)`;

Basicamente, esta deveria ser a saída:

```
SELECT 
    `rank_res`.*,

    @rank:=@rank + 1 rank
FROM
    (SELECT 
        `opn`.`user_id`, SUM(opn.points) AS `total_points`
    FROM
        `olympic_players_niveis` AS `opn`
    WHERE
        (opn.olympic_id = 9)
    GROUP BY `opn`.`user_id`) AS `rank_res`,
     (SELECT @rank:=0) AS `init`
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi desta maneira:

```
 $init = new Zend_Db_Expr(",(SELECT @rank := 0) init");

 $select = $this->dbTable->select()
            ->setIntegrityCheck(false)
            ->from(array('rank_res' => $selectRankQuery),
            array(
                'rank_res.*',
                new Zend_Db_Expr('@rank := @rank + 1 rank')
            ));

$select.=$init;
```